# Unexpected test failure with RSpec and Factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory

RoR Controller:

```
def destroy 
    Page.find(params[:id]).destroy 
    @pagechildren =  Page.where("parent_id = ?", params[:id]) 
    @pagechildren.update_all({parent_id: -1}) if @pagechildren.count > 
0 
    flash[:success] = 
t('activerecord.errors.controllers.message.attributes.page.page_destroy_suc cess') 
    redirect_to pages_path 
  end
```

Test RSpec

```
     it "should remove parent_id from children" do 
       @page2 = Factory(:page) 
       @pagechild = Factory(:page) 
       @pagechild[:parent_id] = @page2.id 
       lambda do 
          delete :destroy, :id => @page2 
        end.should 
change(@pagechild, :parent_id).from(@page2.id).to(-1) 
      end
```

The code works correctly (), but

Код все корректно обрабатывает (catches 'id' delete pages, and for all
children parent_id changes to -1). But rspec test is fail.

Factory:

```
Factory.define :page do |page| 
  page.name "Name example page" 
  page.title "Title example page" 
  page.content "Content example page" 
  page.metadescription "metadescription example page" 
  page.metakeywords "metakeywords example page" 
  page.head "head example page" 
  page.ismenu true 
  page.order_id -1 
  page.parent_id -1 
end
```

test is red =(
what's wrong?

Comment: rspec test says: parent_id is not changed by -1

Comment: Please narrow down which assertion fails and what's the code that is tested by that.

Comment: too much code for a controller action, try to move it to the model, something like: `Page.find(params[:id]).destroy_unsetting_children`. BTW, what database is this that requires the foreign key to be set to `-1` instead of `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code will update all children in the db. but not your test instance :)
try this:

```
it "should remove parent_id from children" do 
       @page2 = Factory.create(:page) 
       @pagechild = Factory.create(:page) 
       @pagechild[:parent_id] = @page2.id 
       delete :destroy, :id => @page2 
       @pagechild.reload.parent_id.should == -1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
delete :destroy, :id => @page2.id
```

and show rspec output if it still doesn't work.